# Magento 2 - Error (ID required) when manually creating an order through the back end

Tags: magento2

Very weird, when I want to manually create an order I get this error? All mandatory fields are filled and I selected a product, shipment provider and a payment method.

[image]

Comment: Need to check log.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue in the multisafepay module. Has been fixed by the vendor